# Seeking framework for navigation and routing for US

Tags: software-recommendations, routing, united-states, navigation, framework

I'm building an app that will have navigation and routing as a primary component (USA Based).  Does anyone have an cross-framework experience or user knowledge on which of the top mapping engines/systems provided the best navigation(ESRI, HERE, BING, Google).  My assumption is that these frames are all using Navteq or some other roads company for the road network so they are roughly the same.

I get a lot of feedback from end users preferring Google but I can't tell if its name recognition or if they have a more comprehensive roads and buildings network to pull from.

What map framework provides great multi point routing/navigation?

Answer (score 2):

I've used Mapquest which has routes from Navteq and is good for routes with waypoints.

Also, read the Terms of Service carefully. You should know that Google does not allow you to use any of their mapping/routing/geocoding services with a navigation app.